# How to mirror flip image in C?

Tags: c

How can i flip an image like its watching itself in the mirror ? I went with a pretty straightforward program. To explain what i did was to make a counter that counts the number of pixels in one horizontal line (which doesn't work) and make an array of pixels as a temporary image line whereas the first pixel of goes to the last place of the array so i can later invert it.

Here is the code, this is the only code there isn't anything else except the declaration of main

```
int main(int argument_count, char ** argument_vector)
```

And here is the code in the main function i repeat this is the only code:

```
    FILE * stream;
    FILE * stream1;
    unsigned int character;
    unsigned int counter = 0;
    if((stream = fopen(* (argument_vector + 1), "rb")) != NULL)
    {
        while((character = fgetc(stream)) != '\n') counter++;
        fclose(stream);
    }
    unsigned int array[counter];
    unsigned int helper = counter;
    if((stream = fopen(* (argument_vector + 1), "rb")) != NULL)
    {
        if((stream1 = fopen(* (argument_vector + 2), "wb")) != NULL)
        {
            while((character = fgetc(stream)) != EOF)
            {
                array[--counter] = character;
                if(counter == 0)
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i < helper; i++)
                    {
                        fputc(array[i], stream1);
                    }
                    counter = helper;
                }
            }
            fclose(stream1);
        }
        fclose(stream);
    }
```

Comment: What kind of image are you reading?  I'm not familiar with an image format that consists of nothing but the raster bytes.

Comment: @DanielWalker Thank you for the reply, as I am new to programming i saw a really simple program that copies some binary files and tried playing around and wanted to mirror flip them. I am using the standard Lena test image > https://www.ece.rice.edu/~wakin/images/ and the code which copies the file is here > https://pastebin.com/nvHZB4C7

Comment: If each pixel only takes up one byte than you could more easily get the number of pixels via `stat` from sys/stat.h.

Comment: **What is the exact name of the file you're using?** Those files are *not* "raw". They have a header specific to the image format (e.g. a bmp header). So you can't do the mirroring ignoring all this. You have to skip the header. You can google the format of the bmp file easily. You'll also want a hex editor to see the bytes in the file for yourself and correlate them with the documentation of the format.